# onActivityResult not getting called; all requirements met

Tags: android, onactivityresult

onActivityResult is not getting called after a child Activity call. I made sure of these:

1. startActivityForResult is called from parent and NOT startActivity
2. setResult is called from child along with finish().
3. No singleInstance launchMode defined in Manifest.

What else could be going wrong?

Comment: show code have you started it using startActivityForResult

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, quickly went to Documentation and found it.

The requestCode got to be >= 0 for the onActivityResult to be called.

Thanks again.